# Structural engineering: Can these studs be removed from a load bearing wall?

Tags: walls, structural, studs, load-bearing

I have a load bearing wall and I want to remove a few studs to create an opening. The three studs have beams around them (top, bottom, and sides). I don't plan to mess with the beams at all. Does it seem reasonable to remove these studs?

Images of the beams and studs here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTaX.jpg

Comment: We need more information: what is the size of the beam above? What is bearing on it? Where in the world are you?

Comment: They almost look like filler pieces, but no way would I tell you to remove them without expert(engineer) opinion.

Comment: Those bolted on attachment plates seem to be way over engineered for a common house build, for a small section, so those studs might be important to hold something heavy from falling on your head, or they could be just to hold the drywall in place.